# Is there a _Imports for Blazor Web Assembly Server Applications?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, webassembly

Simple question:

In Blazor Web Assembly Client applications I can place "global" using statements in the _Imports.razor file.

Is there a similar location in the Server Application where I can add "global" using statements?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Blazor server Application also has _Imports.razor file, where global includes can be defined, for example

```
@using System.Net.Http
```

Comment: "Blazor server Application" is different from "Blazor Web Assembly (Hosted) Server Application". The latter is a separate asp.net API/Host project without an _imports file.

Comment: Sorry, something came up and disappeared for a couple of days.

I wasn't clear, the Blazor Web Assembly (Hosted) Server Application is what I am looking at.

Said another way, Is there something similar to _Imports in the "Server" project in a Web Assembly (Hosted) Blazor Solution's Server project?

Thank you for your help.